# Perl: Access server $ENV in substitution

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I've been looking for way to replace a string with the value of a server `$ENV[KEY]`by using perl substitution in httpd.conf of an Apache server. My code so far:

```
ExtFilterDefine htmlfilter mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|qq(\") $ENV qq(\")|e'"
```

The snippet doesn't work. Does someone has any idea how to fix it? I guess it has something to do with the quotes

```
|qq(\") $ENV qq(\")|
```

I also tried another option and put my perl code inside a `*.pl` file and than put the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
ExtFilterDefine htmlfilter mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|perl env_check.pl|e'"
```

This works as I expected and it's totaly fine. But how can I do it in the first one liner example above?

Comment: *"perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|qq(\") $ENV qq(\")|e"* did you mean to access `$ENV{KEY}` from the `%ENV` hash in Perl? Try `perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|qq(\") . $ENV{KEY} . qq(\")|e"`

Comment: Yes, I mean `%ENV` hash. Great advice. Thank's it works :-). One more further question about it. Is it possible to make an `if statement` inside the one liner of the snippet in comment above? I would like to run my filter (replace string A with string B) only if `$ENV{KEY} = "blue"`. Maybe like this: `perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|blue|e if$==eof & $ENV{KEY} = "blue""`. With `e if$==eof ` I can add the replacement only at the end of the file.

Comment: `perl -0777pe's/Mountainbike$/blue/ if $ENV{KEY} eq q{blue}'` `-0777` causes the whole file to be treated as one line. `$` matches at end of line or before the LF at the end of the line.

Comment: Unfortunalty the `if statement` doesn't work. What could be my issue? Quoting or the `e` is missing? `perl -0777pe 's/Mountainbike$/E-Bike/e if $ENV{KEY} eq q{blue}'`. What about `q{blue}`. Is that right or do you mean `qq(\") . {blue} . qq(\")`?

Comment: What I posted works. It's super easy to prove using `printf 'Mountainbike\nMountainbike\n' | perl ...`. /// That `e` is wrong. `E-Bike` is not valid Perl code. `s{...}{...}` is short for `s{...}{ qq{...} }e` ///  `qq(\") . {blue} . qq(\")` makes no sense. `q{blue}` is the same as a `'blue'` (which i really jsut short for `q'blue'`). By using `q{}` instead of `''` or `""`, I avoid a conflict.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland: Is there a way to also access the super globals `$_SERVER` instead of `%ENV` hash like from your last comment above `perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|qq(\") . $ENV{KEY} . qq(\")|e"`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the value of an env var is done using

```perl
$ENV{KEY}
```

The whole substitution looks like this:

```perl
s/Mountainbike/qq(") . $ENV{KEY} . qq(")/e
```

Simplified:

```perl
s/Mountainbike/qq("$ENV{KEY}")/e
```

Simplified:

```perl
s/Mountainbike/"$ENV{KEY}"/
```

One catch. The quotes tell me you're building a piece of code. What if the value of the environment var contains `"` or another special character? This suffers from a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug. Assuming it's safe to escapes all special characters with `\`, you can solve that problem using the following:

```perl
s/Mountainbike/"\Q$ENV{KEY}\E"/
```

Finally, you need to include in in the directive.

```
... cmd="s/Mountainbike/\"\\Q$ENV{KEY}\\E\"/"
```

Comment: Thank's for the advice about code injection. That's very important and usefull. You are right. Could you also give me some tipps how to use your snippet with an `if statement` like above on top?

Comment: If you have a new question, feel free to post a new Question. Do include a sample input and the output you expect to obtain for that input.